# onreadystatechange() missing on XMLHttpRequest objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
(function (send) {

     XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {

         console.log(this.onreadystatechange); //null
         send.apply(this, arguments);
     };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Why is `this.onreadystatechange` null? According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest) it should exist and be of type `function`.

Comment: The fact that it's `null` and not `undefined` (or throws an undefined exception) should explain - it just hasn't been set yet.

Comment: That function just wraps the `send` method with some logging. We can't tell why the function is `null` when `send` is called because you haven't show us the code that uses it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onreadystatechange` **does** exist...that's why it's `null`. If it didn't exist, it would be `undefined`. It all depends on whether it's been set already. It's clearly already a property because it's `null`...if it weren't, it would be `undefined`...or at least `"onreadystatechange" in this` would be `false`.

Here's an example:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.onreadystatechange = function () {
};
a.send();
```

Your console will log a `function`.

If you had:

```
var b = new XMLHttpRequest();
b.send();
```

Your console would log `null`.

Here's a **demo** of this happening: http://jsfiddle.net/3XKx7/

(I clearly left other steps out for sending an AJAX request, it was just for explanation)

I'm not trying to imply there's a relation between `null` and `undefined` - I'm just saying that when creating a new `XMLHttpRequest`, the `onreadystatechange` will be set to `null` internally. Whether you set it to a function or not is up to you.

**UPDATE**:

The normal way for creating/sending an XHR is this order:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {    // This and `open` could be flip-flopped
    // whatever
};
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send("data=data");
```

I was always told/shown to create the new `XMLHttpRequest`, then whatever order of setting `onreadystatechange` and calling `open`, but only after both of those should I call `send`.

**So**, if that were always done, `onreadystatechange` (if actually set) would not be `null` and would be a `function`.

Since you mentioned you were using jQuery, I decided to test with overriding the `send` method like you want, and making a jQuery `$.ajax` call (not sending a `XMLHttpRequest` manually). Here's my testing - http://jsfiddle.net/3XKx7/1/

It doesn't make sense why `onreadystatechange` would be `null`, because jQuery **has** to be binding to that event in order to know when the request completes and its state. So I decided to look at the jQuery source code. And what I found was that the order they call things is:

```
xhr.open()
xhr.send()
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

};
```

Which means that when you're overriding the `send` method, `onreadystatechange` is `null` since jQuery doesn't set it **before** calling `send`. I don't know their reasoning for it...it might be to prevent things like what you're doing...but I never heard of or saw this convention being used.

So the reason you're getting its value as `null` is because jQuery sets `onreadystatechange` **after** calling `send`. Meaning that when you override `send` and try to access the `onreadystatechange` property, it isn't set yet.

Hopefully this is an example that can help you understand: http://jsfiddle.net/dMP6q/16/

Comment: I'm trying to intercept jquery ajax calls using this. Can't figure out why it would be null (since jQuery obviously is using it)

Comment: @Johan Woah, I think I see what you're saying. Yeah, it doesn't make sense why it would be set to `null`. Here's what I'm testing with http://jsfiddle.net/3XKx7/1/

Comment: I should have been more clear in the question :/ I have no idea how to solve it, though.

Comment: @Johan So, it's a little crazy to me, but I looked through the jQuery source code and think I found the reason. They seem to be calling `send` before setting `onreadystatechange`. I learned, and always saw, the order being `.onreadystatechange = function () {};`, `.open()`, `.send()`. Not sure if they have a reason for it...maybe it's to prevent stuff like what you're doing :) I suspected this in the beginning, but never though they'd actually do this. But can I ask - what exactly do you need to do with `this.onreadystatechange`? Just override it in addition to overriding `send`?

Comment: Thanks for digging deeper in to this :) I need a global ajax listener for ajax code not generated by me (GWT in this case). Can't try it with GWT until monday though, so that's why I tried with jQuery.

Comment: Btw, why does my custom xhr work here? http://jsfiddle.net/dMP6q/12/ I'm setting `.onreadystatechange = function () {};` as well.

Comment: @Johan I updated my answer. Hopefully it's a better explanation than before, because it should've answered this last question of yours :) Let me know if you need more explaining

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for elaborating Ian.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to set it yourself, this function will be called when the state change. It's just like the other event handlers, like `document.onload`, `yourelement.onclick`, etc.

Classically you do

```
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
              if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                  // use httpRequest.responseText
              }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: Random question - do you know why everyone (yes, including me) always uses `httpRequest` **inside** the callback? Why doesn't anyone use `this`? Not that it matters, but I was just wondering. I don't think I've ever seen people use `this`, but I'll see it for normal event handlers.

Comment: I sometimes use this, but I find normal to use the the variable you declared : you know what it is, while you have to know what's the context of the specific callback to use this. That's the same for image's onload.

Comment: That's true. I guess I'm just thinking when setting a reference to a function (not an anonymous function) like `xhr.onreadystatechange = stateChange;`, you can't use `xhr` in the function...you'd have to use `this`. So to me, it makes to always use `this`, since it should always refer to the specific request. Anyways, I guess it's not too important, I just wanted to hear your opinion. Thanks :)